# Secondary tile issue when upgrading WP7 to WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am seeing an issue on Windows Phone when testing an upgrade scenario from a WP7 app with multiple secondary tiles.  In the app, users can pin multiple secondary tiles pointing to sections within the app.

After an upgrade to Windows Phone 8 code on any Windows Phone 8 emulator or actual device, the call to ShellTile.ActiveTiles enumerator function only returns a single secondary tile.  It does return the primary application tile.

This is regardless of how many secondary tiles were pinned in the WP7 version of the app.
I haven’t been able to see any pattern of which secondary tile is chosen. Sometimes it’s the first one pinned, sometimes it’s the last.  However, on subsequent passes of the scheduled agent it always finds the same one in the ActiveTiles call.  This results in only one secondary tile being updated after the upgrade is complete.

Only workaround is to delete and add the secondary tile again using the new WP8 version of the code.

Is this a known issue or any thoughts?

Comment: can you share your code snippet for handling pinning?